# After mapping data in order to change to integer, variable only showing NaN value

Tags: python, pandas, database, sqlite, jupyter-notebook

So I was having trouble with a NaN error where asking for df['column'] was only showing NaN and I've narrowed it down to this specific part of the code and i think it has something to do with the way I have mapped the data. Does anyone have any idea?

**My code is below:**

```
df['country_code'] = df['country_code'].replace(['?'], ) - *there were some '?' values so I wanted to make this empty so that i could later replace with the mean once I'd converted everything to integer*
country_code_map = {'AUS': 1, 'USA': 2, 'CAN': 3, 'BGD': 4, 'BRZ': 5, 'JP': 6, 'ID': 7, 'HR': 8, 'CH': 9, 'FRA': 10, 'FIN': 11}
df['country_code'] = df['country_code'].map(country_code_map)
df['country_code'] = pd.to_numeric(df['country_code'])
df['country_code'] = df['country_code'].replace([''], df['country_code'].mean)
```

Let me know if any extra info req'd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I realised the issue was in my mapping and converting to an integer. It will automatically do this once I have mapped the data.

**Therefore the code should look like this:**

```
country_code_map = {'AUS': 1, 'USA': 2, 'CAN': 3, 'BGD': 4, 'BRZ': 5, 'JP': 6, 'ID': 7, 'HR': 8, 'CH': 9, 'FRA': 10, 'FIN': 11}
df['country_code'] = df['country_code'].map(country_code_map)
```

Then I can check the mean without getting the NaN values as I was before:

```
df['country_code'].mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created `df['country_code']` in the following way, you should have something similar:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'country_code': ["?", "BRZ", "USA"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  country_code
0            ?
1          BRZ
2          USA
```

Now if I execute your code, this is what I get:

```
   country_code
0           NaN
1           5.0
2           2.0
```

You're getting a NaN value in the output instead of a mean over the column for the following reason.

Let's take a look at this line:

```
df['country_code'] = df['country_code'].replace(['?'], )
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   country_code
0           NaN
1           5.0
2           2.0
```

Here you're not erasing the `?`s leaving the place empty, but you're filling it with NaN values.

So when you get to the last line, what you're trying to do is to replace empty strings `''`, but you have NaNs. What you should use instead is [`DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), to fill the NaNs, like this:

```
df['country_code'] = df['country_code'].replace(['?'], ) 
country_code_map = {'AUS': 1, 'USA': 2, 'CAN': 3, 'BGD': 4, 'BRZ': 5, 'JP': 6, 'ID': 7, 'HR': 8, 'CH': 9, 'FRA': 10, 'FIN': 11}
df['country_code'] = df['country_code'].map(country_code_map)
df['country_code'] = pd.to_numeric(df['country_code'])
df['country_code'] = df['country_code'].fillna(df['country_code'].mean())
```

Output:

```
   country_code
0           3.5
1           5.0
2           2.0
```